# system("foo.exe") requires to close foo in order to continue my program

Tags: c++, windows

I don't know if my question is clear, let me explain.

I call this in my `main()` function:

```
system("foo.exe")
```

But, in order to execute following commands, I first need to manually close the `foo.exe` window.

I tried to use:

```
system("taskkill /F /im foo.exe")
```

But it doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Comment: `system()` doesn't return until the command finishes.

Comment: if you need a child process I would suggest considering [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `system`

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
std::system("start foo.exe")
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but a little background explanation about *why* this solution works wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hoping for this to work:

```
 system("foo.exe");
 system("taskkill /F /im foo.exe");
```

it can't because the second call will only take place once the first execution of `foo.exe` terminates. If for some reason you need to start a process, and then later kill it before it would naturally terminate (and you probably *really* don't want to do that), you need to look at the more sophisticated Windows process control APIs, beginning with CreateProcess.

Comment: I'd be interested in the thinking behind the down-vote.

Comment: I have no choice. In order to solve a physics problem, I need to call another program which is called femm in order to calculate a magnetic force using a stress tensor. I cannot do it inside my code. I will definitely look into CreateProcesses for further coding though

Comment: You are really bad at describing your problem - I still don't see how @HollyBlackCat's answer solves whatever it is.

Comment: It appears to be doing so because system("start foo.exe") doesn't wait for foo.exe to close. It just starts the exe then move on to the next command.

Comment: `start foo.exe` executes the batch command `start` which then executes it's input in a separate non-blocking process. Basically this is a really round about and expensive way to do `CreateProcess`

Comment: Yes, I know what "start" does, I simply don't see how this relates to your question.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Isn't it obvious? The problem is that `system("foo.exe")` blocks `main()` until `foo.exe` exits, so the workaround is to use `system("start foo.exe")` to block until `start` exits, which itself does not block waiting for `foo.exe` to exit.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, `system("command")` launches a new process for `cmd.exe /C command`.  The `/C` tells `cmd.exe` to terminate when `command` is finished.  `system()` waits for `cmd.exe` to exit.

In your case, `system("foo.exe")` is waiting for `cmd.exe /C foo.exe` to exit, which in turn is waiting for `foo.exe` to exit.  That is why you have to close the `foo.exe` window before `system("foo.exe")` returns control to your code.

You *can* use `system("start foo.exe")`, like HolyBlackCat suggested. `system()` will wait for `cmd.exe /C start` to exit, and `start` will NOT wait for `foo.exe` to exit, thus allowing `system("start foo.exe")` to return your code while `foo.exe` is still running.

A better solution is to call the Win32 API [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) function directly and avoid `cmd.exe` altogether:

```
#include <windows.h>

STARTUPINFO si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
// populate si as desired...

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

if (CreateProcess("foo.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    // other commands while foo.exe is still running...
}
```